# Pretty Print JSON output from Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

For dev it'd be nice to see the resulting JSON pretty printed. And tips for configuring loopback so i can see that?

I've scanned through the docs for a config setting. Must be missing something.

Comment: Use your own stringify function? `JSON.stringify(jsObject, null, 3)`

Comment: Place above code where? I can do that for Remote Methods but i am referring to the generated endpoints. Cheers for suggesting though.